# --no-home Singularity flag doesn't work on Docker container in a cluster node

Tags: docker, hpc, singularity-container

When I use a Docker container on a HPC cluster's login machine using Singularity, it works as expected and I can access the container's /home:

```
singularity exec docker://quay.io/comparative-genomics-toolkit/cactus:v2.7.1 ls /home
```

When I run the same command on the computing node, I have access to the node's /home instead of the container's one:

```
srun singularity exec docker://quay.io/comparative-genomics-toolkit/cactus:v2.7.1 ls /home
```

I tried with `--no-home`, `--contain` and `--containall`, it makes no difference.

Both machines have the same version of Singularity and the same `singularity.conf` file.

How can I get the container's /home on the cluster's node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--no-mount hostfs` option was the only one that worked to prevent `/home` from being mounted. the problem is that it prevents everything from being mounted, so I had to manually bind the folders I needed.

So the working command is

```
singularity exec --no-mount hostfs --bind $PWD:$PWD docker://quay.io/comparative-genomics-toolkit/cactus:v2.7.1 ls /home
```

Maybe it is worth to note that my `$HOME` folder wasn't in `/home`. It could explain why `--no-home` had no effect. But it still doesn't explain why there is a difference between the login machine and the node machine.